# cUrl request after fastcgi_finish_request() don't work with some urls

Tags: php, fastcgi, php-curl, php-7.3

I have a php script (7.3.33) sending requests to an API ([HereGeocodingApi](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics-api/code-geocode-address.html)). I use `fastcgi_finish_request()` for saving datas in MySQL database even if the user is disconnected.

My problem occurs specifically when i call the `curl_exec()` function with some specific urls. Surprisingly it work perfectly fine without `fastcgi_finish_request()`. And more even difficult to understand, the error occurs only on some urls, not for all of them.

### Code

the php script look like this *(shortened for the example)*

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
ignore_user_abort(true);

// ... some stuff here before returning response

echo json_encode($processDatas);
fastcgi_finish_request();

$key = "MY_API_KEY";

// this work perfectly fine with or without fastcgi_finish_request() when :
//$adress = "2 AVENUE ANATOLE FRANCE, 91260 JUVISY SUR ORGE";

// this work without fastcgi_finish_request() but shut down otherwise when :
$adress = "3 AVENUE DU GENERAL DE GAU, 94240 L HAY LES ROSES";

$result = here_geocoderManager($key, $adress);

function here_geocoderManager($apikey, $adress){
    $response = "error";
    $datas = [
        "q" => $adress,
        "apikey" => $apikey
    ]; 
    $apiRequest = http_build_query($datas);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?" . $apiRequest);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    try{
        // with this line replace by >> $curlResponse=["test"]; << the script end correctly anytime
        $curlResponse = curl_exec($curl);
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        $response = $e;
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}

?>
```

### What i've tried so far

1. combination of one or all of :

   - **CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT** :: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);`
   - **CURLOPT_TIMEOUT** :: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);`
   - **CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER** :: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $A_CUSTOM_HEADER);`
2. Exactly the same problem occurs with `file_get_contents()`
3. Add `set_time_limit(20)` before `curl_init()` (request response is under 1 second when it works)

Any thought? some ideas would be helpful.

Comment: ```$curlstderr = fopen("curl_log.log","ab);curl_setopt_array($curl,array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>$curlstderr));``` and show us the log.

Answer (score 0):

I checking this function how works i found this `ignore_user_abort(true); fastcgi_finish_request();`

Comment: i researching deep what exactly doing after close connection and what is not available